# Separate Object into equal chunks by a grid

Tags: mesh, objects

I have an terrain object that I want to divide into chunks of the same size. I already created a grid (black lines) with that I could slice the mesh. I want every chunk to be a separate object. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Knife project -> edge split -> separate by loose parts

Comment: Hi Allen, although i used Blender once or twice...i don't get it. after i made knife project on my displaced plane with my plane above, i got this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjLTG.png is this already wrong? if i do edge split on that and separate by loose parts, i got way to many parts: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEOR.jpg so maybe a more detailed answer would help...at least me...a knife project beginner

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Knife project works fine, but as Chris mentioned, edge split and separate by loose parts wont create squared chunks.  A more detailed answer would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I tried that workflow and it worked for me. This is what I did:

1. Create the grid deleting all the faces:
   [image]
2. Create a simple plane and rotate it for some variation:
   [image]
3. Apply knife project with the grid on the plane:
   [image]
4. Add Edge Split modifier:

[image]

5. Set angle to 0 degrees to apply to all edges:

[image]

6. Apply modifier and enter edit mode to check if all chunks are detached:
   [image]
7. Apply Separate by loose parts:

[image]

8. Check that all expected objects have been created:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, with your super simple setup where the plane isn't subdivided at all...that's easy. Now subdivide your plane 30 times and do it again...and it won't work. Cutting a non subdivided plane might be good for demo purposes...but in reality in CG a plane has subdivisions...And a terrain object i would guess has subdivision, else you won't get height in it.

Comment: How would I get split objects in the case where I have topology on these chunks? The edge split won't work here for me.